# Help with integrating stochastic calculus expression from yield curve model

Tags: integration, finance

I am very rusty on stochastic calculus, and I am having trouble integrating the following simple term from a yield curve model:

$$z(t)=\int_0^t\exp(-k(t-s))dW(s)$$

Any suggestions appreciated.

[question edited - subscripts came out wrong before, and they are not essential to the question, so I just removed them].

Comment: There is something wrong with that differential...

Comment: Again, what is $W(s)$?